# Disable firebase-crash reporting with use of config.xml in cordova

Tags: cordova, firebase, cordova-plugins, firebase-crash-reporting

I am using `cordova-plugin-firebase` plugin what i want to do is disable `firebase-crash reporting` with use of `cordovas s config.xml` file.

I know how to do this with  `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_crash_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

But if i remove android platform from cordova  `AndroidManifest.xml` also remove so i need to set it up again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom hook that will trigger after or before the build process.

You can check more information and examples here
[Ionic Package Hooks](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-package-hooks)